# 'gnome-screensaver-command -l' doesn't work when called from '/etc/pm/sleep.d'-script

Tags: arch-linux, suspend, hook

I am using Archlinux and trying to let my notebook [lock the screen via the instructions given on wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pm-utils#Locking_the_screen_saver_on_hibernate_or_suspend) before it suspends.

Calling `gnome-screensaver-command -l` only locks my screen, when I call it manually - but not when it is called automatically before a system-suspend.

I verified that the script, that is placed under `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` actually works by calling it with `. /etc/pm/sleep.d/00screensaver-lock suspend` positive.

Also I veriefied that the line

```
su $username -c "/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command -l"
```

is executed by the system through adding

```
su $username -c "touch /home/user/.suspend-hook-runs-screensaver-lock"
```

before the `gnome-screensaver-command`-command.

Can anybody tell me, why the `gnome-screensaver-command`-command locks the screen when I call it myself, but not when it is called by the system?